# React-native-maps rerenders every time state changes

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps) in a react-native project. I'm showing a map like this:

```
<MapView
  camera={{
    center: {
      latitude: location.lat,
      longitude: location.lng
    },
    altitude: 500,
    zoom: 12
  }}
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
/>
```

I have a TextInput-component below this map. I'm using the `useState()`-hook to keep track of the value of the TextInput-component.

The problem is that every time the states updates through the TextInput-component, the map re-renders. I tried wrapping it in a `React.memo()`-function but it still keeps re-rendering every time.

The `location`-props from the map are from a custom `useLocation`-hook, I'm using [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/michalchudziak/react-native-geolocation) to get the current location of the user to show it on a map.

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract style and camera like this:

```js
import React, {useMemo} from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: { width: '100%', height: '100%' }
})

const Component = () => {
  const camera = useMemo(() => ({
    center: {
      latitude: location.lat,
      longitude: location.lng
    },
    altitude: 500,
    zoom: 12
  }), [location.lat, location.lng])


  return (
    <MapView
      camera={camera}
      style={styles.map}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: To bad, the same thing happens.

Comment: @SamLeurs can you share the full component? Probably you have a parent which rerender all childs